# Rerender DOM elements of components in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I read about, how ExtJS4 keeps all the data of the components in separate objects and just renders DOM stuff on demand.

I have the problem, that a `<div>` gets a `innerHTML = ''` to hide some data and afterwards fills the `innerHTML` if the data is demanded.

If I render a component into that `<div>` it gets deleted when the hide functionallity is activated.

But all the component data is stored in a separate object, so is it possible to just re-render the stuff with its last state or just tell ExtJS to delete the DOM stuff by itself before it gets deleted and afterwards re-render it?

--- Edit ---

I think I found the problem (but no good solution)

When I define the component, I specify a `<div>` in `renderTo` if the parent `<div>` gets the `innerHTML = ''` it gets deleted, but later it gets recreated, with the same ID and stuff.

So when I call `show()` a `<div>` with the right ID exists, but it's a new object and the object I specified in the `renderTo` option is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 2 `<div>`, the first will be for direct manipulation with `innerHTML`; the second is for the Component. When you hide by setting innerHTML, you can do hide the next Component. Re-render will be the reverse steps.

Comment: Problem is, I have no control over the `<div>`. I'm just allowed to render to it. If it's `innerHTML` gets overwritten, I can fire an event to do some stuff, also if it's get back to normal. But when I try to just use `show()` later, nothing happens :\